# Children input actions in react parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Form component which should get form elements like inputs, buttons etc. How i can detect `onChange` or `onClick` events or `value` if they passed like `children`? For example i change the second input and how detect that i change exactly second input but not another

I need to detect all actions in Form component

```js
const Form = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  
  const onChangeHandler = () => {
      //detect change input
  }
  
  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
const App = () => {
    return <Form>
       <input style={{width: '100%'}}/>
       <input style={{width: '100%'}}/>
       <input style={{width: '100%'}}/>
    </Form>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the React.cloneElement method?

```
const Form = ({children, ...rest}) => {

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value
    const id = e.target.id
    console.log(value, id)
  }

  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          onChange: onChangeHandler
        })
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
const App = () => {
    return <Form>
       <input id="input1" />
       <input id="input2" />
       <input id="input3" />
    </Form>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Update: yes sorry it was untested, there's no way the input would know about the Form onChangeHandler so you just map it to the onChange in cloneElement.

I've added id attributes to each input so that you can see how the value for each input is change in the onChangeHandler. If you are wanting to save the value to state you can then use this id as a key in something like Redux.

Comment: You code contains some error - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-8y6rf?fontsize=14

Comment: you're right I hadn't tested it and there's no way the input would know about the Form onChangeHandler so it should just map to the onChange in cloneElement. I have updated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`React.cloneElement` is what you need for this.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html),

> Clone and return a new React element using element as the starting
>   point. The resulting element will have the original element’s props
>   with the new props merged in shallowly. New children will replace
>   existing children. key and ref from the original element will be
>   preserved.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Form = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    //detect change input
    const value = e.target.value
    const name = e.target.name
    console.log('You have changed ', name, ' with value ', value)
  }

  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          onChange: onChangeHandler,
          name: `input${index + 1}`,
        })
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <input />
      <input />
      <input />
    </Form>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-gi6u1?fontsize=14)